# C++ wrap multiple returns

Tags: c++, function, return

I have the following code which returns ERROR in many lines:

```
bool func()
{
    if (acondition)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int cmdfun()
{
    other_funcs;
    if (func()) return ERROR#NUMBER;
    other_funcs;
    if (func()) return ERROR#NUMBER;
}
```

But I found its becoming longer and longer. How can I encapsulate return ERROR#NUMBER into func() also? Or any way to encapsulate if (func()) return ERROR; into another independent function?

Comment: Why not using exceptions which were designed for that case?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Its about encapsulate return for the call stack like  func()->cmdfun()->main(), so that func() can return ERROR directly to main(), so there will be no need to put return ERROR in cmdfun().

Comment: You cannot _encapsulate return_ Use exceptions as mentioned instead.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ But it is not an exception. Its just double return and encapsulate return.

Comment: It's simple, you can't encapsulate return calls, use exceptions instead. I can't help with facts you don't want  to hear.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ, how do you say i define a macro that encapsulateif (func()) return ERROR#NUMBER; and then calls this macro in cmdfun(), which encapsulate return.

Comment: A macro is the worst thing to consider. What's your problem with using exceptions as advised?

Comment: But I previously dont know it is a solution, and no one here is helping with that.

Comment: Well, if you're keeping resistant to receive help, what should we do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said it is not an exception and cannot be handled by std::exception, it is just an error message and ERROR#NUMBER is just another macro. And I cannot access to the caller to cmdfun(). So unable to adopt the first answer. But after asked someone else, it is possible to encapsulate returns and save time when typing them, though it's not recommended, but in this particular case, I can use macro. A complete example is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define CHECK_VEC(acondition)\
if(checkcondition(acondition)) return -1;

bool checkcondition(bool acondition)
{
    if (acondition) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int fun_called_by_main()
{
    int a = 5 + 4;
    bool acondition = a;
    CHECK_VEC(acondition);

    return 1;
}


int main()
{
    int a = fun_called_by_main();

    cout << a << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't really achieve this using `return` on its own.

But you *could* `throw` an exception in `func` which will bubble up the call stack, in the way you seem to want program control to:

```
struct myexception{}; /*ToDo - inherit from std::exception?*/
bool func()
{
    if (acondition){
        return 0; /*normal behaviour, perhaps make `func` void if not needed?*/
    }
    throw myexception();
}
```

`cmdfun` then takes the form:

```
int cmdfun()
{
    other_funcs;
    func();
    other_funcs;
    func();
    /* don't forget to return something*/
}
```

Finally, make sure you `catch` the exception in the caller to `cmdfun`.

Answer (score -2):

If I understood corectly your question, you are asking for an 'error reporter' for **your own** errors. There are 2 solutions for 2 separate cases:

Case 1 - you still want to use a return statement to make an 'error reporter':

To do this, you'll have to make another function or just learn how to use goto. However, you don't need to - your function returns a boolean(bool) - which means you only have 2 possible results: 0 (False) and 1 (True)

```
bool func()
{
    if (acondition)
    {
        return (bool)0; // False (no error)
    }
    return (bool)1; // True (error)
    // Note: I used (bool)0 and (bool)1 because it is 
    // more correct because your returning type is bool.
}

void errorcase(bool trueorfalse)
{
    switch(trueorfalse)
    {
    case False:
        ... // your code (func() returned 0)
        break;
    default:
        ... // your code (func() returned 1)
        break;

        // Note that you will not need to check if an error occurred every time.
    }
    return;
}

int cmdfun()
{
    ... // your code
    errorcase(func());
    ... // again - your code
    return 0; // I suppouse that you will return 0... 
}
```

But I think that the second case is more interesting (unfortunetly it is also preety hard to understand as a beginner and the first solution might be a lot easier for you):

Case 2 - you decided to do it somehow else - that's by learning throw and catch - I won't repeat the answer because it is already given: @Bathsheba answered preety good...

Comment: Basically I want to return ERROR in the function called cmdfun(), e.g. main(), from the function called by cmdfun() directly, here is func(). So the stack is func()->cmdfun()->main(), but I want func() to be the one who directly return ERROR to main().

Comment: _@VVI C And C 15_ Don't let the OP keeping to bark up the wrong tree. There's not much value in your answr.